# I need to generate 50 Millions Rows csv file with random data: how to optimize this program?

Tags: rebol

The program below can generate random data according to some specs (example here is for 2 columns)

It works with a few hundred of thousand lines on my PC (should depend on RAM). I need to scale to dozen of millions row.

How can I optimize the program to write directly to disk ? Subsidiarily how can I "cache"  the parsing rule execution as it is always the same pattern repeated 50 Millions times ?

Note: to use the program below, just type generate-blocks and save-blocks output will be db.txt

```
Rebol[]

specs: [
    [3 digits 4 digits 4 letters]
    [2 letters 2 digits]
]

;====================================================================================================================


digits: charset "0123456789"
letters: charset "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
separator: charset ";"

block-letters: [A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z]

blocks: copy []

generate-row: func[][
    Foreach spec specs [

        rule: [

            any [

                [
                    set times integer! [['digits (                          
                                repeat n times [                    
                                block: rejoin [block random 9]                          
                            ]

                            )
                            | 
                            'letters (repeat n times [                  
                                block: rejoin [ block to-string pick block-letters random 24]                       
                            ]

                            )
                        ]
                        |
                        [
                            'letters (repeat n times [block: rejoin [ block to-string pick block-letters random 24]                     
                            ]

                            )       
                            | 
                        'digits (repeat n times [block: rejoin [block random 9]]

                        )   
                        ]
                    ]
                    |
                    {"} any separator {"}
                ]

            ]

            to end

        ]
        block: copy ""
        parse spec rule
        append blocks block
    ]
]

generate-blocks: func[m][
  repeat num m [  
    generate-row
  ]
]

quote: func[string][
    rejoin [{"} string {"}]
]

save-blocks: func[file][
    if exists? to-rebol-file file [
        answer: ask rejoin ["delete " file "? (Y/N): "]
        if (answer = "Y") [
            delete %db.txt
        ]
    ]
    foreach [field1 field2] blocks [
        write/lines/append %db.txt rejoin [quote field1 ";" quote field2]
    ]
]
```

Comment: AFAIK no cache in parse.  For dealing with large output files, you'll need ports, I've never used them because my Rebol projects have not needed to deal with such scaling.  They were rethought in Rebol 3: http://www.rebol.com/docs/core23/rebolcore-14.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use open with /direct and /lines refinement to write directly to file without buffering the content:

```
file: open/direct/lines/write %myfile.txt
loop 1000 [
  t: random "abcdefghi"
  append file t
]
Close file
```

This will write 1000 random lines without buffering.
You can also prepare a block of lines (lets say 10000 rows) then write it directly to file, this will be faster than writing line-by-line.

```
file: open/direct/lines/write %myfile.txt
loop 100 [
  b: copy []
  loop 1000 [append b random "abcdef"]
  append file b
]
close file
```

this will be much faster, 100000 rows less than a second.
Hope this will help.

Note that, you can change the number 100 and 1000 according to your needs an memory of your pc, and use b: make block! 1000 instead of b: copy [], it will be faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have cheated by launching several rebol instances :) I will now try to incorporate your suggestions.