# How to bind to foreach context?

Tags: rebol

Currently I have this snippet of code:

```
    Blocks: ["F4369RO771" "282273" "5" "146" "126" "6-Nov-2009" "8-Jan-2010" "7-Jun-2010" "8"
"M9881KI923" "399727" "2" "359" "443" "5-Aug-2010" "23-Feb-2010" "6-Nov-2009" "4"
]

save-blocks: func[file /local f out][
    foreach [field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 field6 field7 field8 field9] blocks [

out: copy ""
repeat n 9 [
  part: get bind to-word rejoin ["field" n] 'field1 
  out: rejoin [out part ";"]
]
        remove back tail out
        write/lines/append f out


]
```

It's not generic enough, I'd like to pass this instead

```
block: [field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 field6 field7 field8 field9]
```

as parameter and write something like this:

```
save-blocks: func[block file /local f out][
    foreach block blocks [

out: copy ""
repeat n length? block [
  part: get bind to-word rejoin ["field" n] 'field1 
  out: rejoin [out part ";"]
]
        remove back tail out
        write/lines/append f out


]
```

But I don't know how to bind in this case too hard for me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(For the moment, disregarding the question of whether what you're doing here is a good idea.  :P)*

Remember that when you pass a `block!` to `foreach`, it will bind the words inside that block during the loop:

```
>> foreach [foo bar] ["a" "b"] [print foo print bar]
a
b
```

When you pass a `word!` of any kind, it will be overwritten completely and no variables will be assigned (regardless of whether that word was bound to previously to a block!):

```
>> foobarblock: [foo bar]

>> foreach foobarblock ["a" "b"] [print foo print bar]
** Script error: foo has no value
** Where: foreach
** Near: foreach foobarblock ["a" "b"] [print foo print bar]

>> foreach foobarblock ["a" "b"] [print foobarblock]
a
b
```

To get the effect you seem to be desiring here, you need something like:

```
>> foreach :foobarblock ["a" "b"] [print foo print bar]
a
b
```

The behavior would then be what you expect, with the words bound in the local context.

Comment: Great thanks you're really IT Genious from a poor brain trying to just get things done :) 

If you would not disregard what I'm trying to do, it's just related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768563/i-need-to-generate-50-millions-rows-csv-file-with-random-data-how-to-optimize-th 

I want to allow users to specify any number of fields for their specs so that they won't have to modify the save function each time.

If there is some more elegant way, I would be pleased to learn it of course :D

Comment: In the other question you asked it's not clear to me what value you get out of trying to do this by passing a block to foreach in this idiomatic style.  Just pass an ordinary word - it will assigned the value of the record with however many fields...then have an inner loop to go through that.

Comment: See this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326484/extending-build-markup-with-repeat-refinement